# Data structures: map, Collectors, groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

Can somebody help with Map, Collectors and groupingBy?

Code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ZkKwLvGe

```
    //TODO: aggregate bills that have same billNumber, date and customerId
    Map<Integer, BigDecimal> map = bills.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Bill::getBillNumber,
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Bill::getNetAmount, BigDecimal::add)));
```

I want to sum up Bill's net amount, but first bills should be aggregated by billNumber, date and customerId.

So the result of this program should be:
30.50

34.50

15.00

10.00

Currently it only aggregating by billNumber.

Answer (score 1):

First create a composite key:

```
//@AllArgsConstructor // better to use Lombok if it's possible
//@Getter
//@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CompositeBillKey {
    private final Integer billNumber;
    private final Date billDate;
    private final String customerId;

    public Integer getBillNumber() {
        return billNumber;
    }

    public Date getBillDate() {
        return billDate;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public CompositeBillKey(Integer billNumber, Date billDate, String customerId) {
        this.billNumber = billNumber;
        this.billDate = billDate;
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CompositeBillKey that = (CompositeBillKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(billNumber, that.billNumber) && Objects.equals(billDate, that.billDate) && Objects.equals(customerId, that.customerId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(billNumber, billDate, customerId);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Map<CompositeBillKey, BigDecimal> billNumberToNetAmount = bills.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> 
                      new CompositeBillKey(b.getBillNumber(), b.getBillDate(), b.getCustomerId()),
                Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Bill::getNetAmount, BigDecimal::add)));
```

Output:

```
30.50
34.50
15.00
10.00
```